# I want to switch to Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit from a 64-bit without losing data and getting my windows on dual boot damaged

Tags: dual-boot

I hope somebody is going t help me out with this. I am a student, so it is my need at present

Comment: If you are wanting to switch from 64-bit to 32-bit because of problems with your installation, switching is almost certainly not going to solve whatever problem it was.  Would you like to give more information about the reason for wanting to switch?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell s why you want this. It is very complicated to change the archiecture so perhaps another soltion might be more feasible for you than downgrading (e.g. using a VM).